# read from serial port fails when called twice

Tags: c, linux, unix, serial-port

Resolved Bellow: Wrong number of characters in read/write

I am attempting to read and write to a serial port, and I don't have much experience in C/C++.

My port is connected to a motion controller/driver that requires the following settings:

- Baudrate: 57600
- Data bits: 8
- Parity: None
- Stop bits: 1
- Flow control: Xon/Xoff
- Terminator CRLF

Problem: The code will write and read my first command,but it hangs on the second read call. I am currently blocking until I receive at least one character, but each written command should generate a return.

Additional information: I can only run the first write/read if I first unplug the remote and plug it back in. Alternatively, I can open a cool term window, setup my serial port and run a few commands. When I close the cool term window I will be able to write/read once.

Current Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int open_port(void)
{
        int fd;

     // open file descriptor
        fd = open("/dev/cu.USA19H41P1.1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

     // if unsucessful
        if (fd == -1)
        {
                printf("open_port: unable to open port. \n");
        }
        else
        {
             // remains open across executables
                fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
                printf("port is open. \n");
        }
        return (fd);
 }

int configure_port(int fd)
{

     // store terminal port settings
        struct termios port_settings;
        memset(&port_settings, 0, sizeof port_settings);
        if(tcgetattr(fd, &port_settings) !=0)
        {
                printf("error tcgetattr \n");
                cout << errno;
        }

        port_settings.c_iflag = 0;
        port_settings.c_oflag = 0;
        port_settings.c_lflag = 0;
        port_settings.c_cflag = 0;

     // flush
        tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);

     // set baud rate
        cfsetispeed(&port_settings, B57600);
        cfsetospeed(&port_settings, B57600);

     // xon/xoff requirment
        port_settings.c_iflag |= IXON;
        port_settings.c_iflag |= IXOFF;

     // no parity requirement
        port_settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;

     // one stop bin requirement
        port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;

     // turn on read
        port_settings.c_cflag |= CREAD;
        port_settings.c_cflag |= CLOCAL;

     // no character processing and 8 bit input
        port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
        port_settings.c_cflag |= CS8;

     // one character blocking 
        port_settings.c_cc[VMIN]  = 1;
        port_settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;

     // apply above settings
       if(tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW, &port_settings) != 0)
        {
                printf("error tcsetattr \n");
                cout << errno;
        }

     // flush buffers one more time
        tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);

        return(fd);
}

int read_write(int fd)
{
        // write to serial port
        ssize_t size=write(fd, "1va?\r\n", 8);
        // wait until output is transmitted
        tcdrain(fd);

        // read from serial port
        char buf[100];
        memset(buf, '\0', sizeof buf);
        ssize_t size2=read(fd, &buf, sizeof(buf));
        cout << buf << endl;
        return(fd);
 }


int main(void)
{
 // open port
 int fd = open_port();

// store old settings
struct termios old_settings;
memset(&old_settings, 0, sizeof old_settings);
tcgetattr(fd,&old_settings);

// configure port
configure_port(fd);

// write/read first command ("1va?\r\n")
read_write(fd);

// write read second command ("1pa?\r\n")
ssize_t size=write(fd, "1pa?\r\n", 8);
tcdrain(fd);
char buf[100];
memset(buf, '\0', sizeof buf);
ssize_t size3=read(fd, &buf, sizeof(buf));
cout << buf;

//close serial port
close(fd);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &old_settings);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you do about it?

Comment: COuld you show the code, please

Comment: There is no language C/C++!

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter before I was done editing the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/roelstorms/Qt_ZigbeeWSN/blob/master/SerialCom/connection.cpp) is some example code on working with Serial ports setting the correct flags and the baud rate:

Provide your code and and more thorough explanation for us to resolve your issue. What do you mean by write and read my first command? Is your device still responsive after this command? Isn't the second command sent?

Comment: The second write command seems to send. If I do 'cout << size' I get the expected 8, not an error.

Comment: ssize_t size=write(fd, "1va?\r\n", 8);
If I'm not mistaking the string "1va?\r\n" has a length of 6. Maybe something is wrong there. \r and \n is 1 character

Comment: I think you just resolved it! I've been staring at that for like 2 days now.

Comment: Take in mind that \ is an escape character. It's a way to write some ASCII characters like returns and tabs. So \r is actually 0x0d (in hex) and only 1 byte long. If this resolved your issue can you accept my anwser please.